# r - cannot install recharts from github using install.packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm trying to install recharts - https://github.com/yihui/recharts, but it seems to be saving the installed packages in a temporary folder, and when I do library('recharts'), I get: 'recharts' is not a valid installed package.

I tried unzipping and mannually pasting into the libraries folder in R, but it still does not work.

Comment: It's working fine on my machine Mac OS X Yosemite and RStudio. Could you please let us know your machine configuration ?

Comment: What happens if you type `install.packages(
  'recharts',
  repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.com')
)`?

Comment: You need to install.packages first - I'd use devtools::install_github("yihui/recharts")

Comment: Yes I did this - I followed the instructions on the website

Comment: How about your R version? Your output of `R.version.string` should give a version number >= 3.2.0 according to the website.

Comment: @RHertel - After I type that, I get severall warnings - http status was '404 not found', 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file; installation of package 'recharts' had non-zero exit status

Comment: @RHertel - yes, I have R 3.2.1, but I just installed it, so it's possible that something isn't set up right which is causing the issue

Comment: @jeremycg - I tried this, and I get: Downloading github repo yihui/recharts@master
Installing recharts
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpwdWGTp/devtools7cc01f452c37/yihui-recharts-4abe1de"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: @md1630 I'm afraid I can't help here. I just installed the `recharts` package and on my computer it works without any problem.

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue relating to windows - you have a space in your path to R that R doesn't like. Try updating R/RStudio/Rtools, if that doesnt work, try reading here - https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/333

Comment: @jeremycg - yes! I was on the same thought - I reinstalled R into a file path with no spaces in it and it works. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: to anyone else using this package, please make sure that you also download the R studio version  0.99.447 or higher (in addition to the latest version of R), otherwise there may be another error: Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'